# Cordova Platform add android issues

Tags: android, cordova, windows-8

I'm trying to add the android platform however this is the error message I keep getting

> C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Mtek_DM\Mtek>cordova -d platform add android
>   cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download.
>   Continuing. Checking if platform "android" passes minimum
>   requirements... Creating android project... Running command:
>   C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\create.b at
>   --cli C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Mtek_DM\Mtek\platforms\android org.xtek.Mtek Mt ek
>
> C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
>       at C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:
>   87:29
>       at _rejected (C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_mo
>   dules\q\q.js:808:24)
>       at C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.j
>   s:834:30
>       at Promise.when (C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node
>   _modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cor
>   dova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
>       at C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.j
>   s:574:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_module
>   s\q\q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13) Command finished with error code 8: C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova
>   \3.5.1\bin\create.bat
>   --cli,C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Mtek_DM\Mtek\platforms\andro id,org.xtek.Mtek,Mtek Error:
>   C:\Users\Xavier.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\create.bat:
>   Comman d failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Xavier\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
>   ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)

Furthermore, I created my System environments at

> ANDROID_HOME =C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Android\sdk\platform-tools
>   ANT_HOME = C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Android\apache_ant1.9.4 JAVA_HOME =
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

And linked them under my variable PATH as

> C:\Users\Xavier\AppData\Roaming\npm;%ANT_HOME%/bin;%ANDROID_HOME%/tools;%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%/bin

Am I missing something? because when I typein java in the command line it works but for ant i get "buildfile: build.xml does not exist! build fail"

Comment: yup you need to install ant.Check this blog.Really helped you...http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.no/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html

Comment: **"buildfile: build.xml does not exist! build fail"** doesn't mean that ant isn't working, just that it didn't find a build.xml file in the current directory.

Comment: I think ANDROID_HOME should point to `\sdk\`, not `\sdk\platform-tools`. This is because the build system uses things in both `platform-tools`, and `tools`.  Change that and try again in a new terminal window please.

Comment: Thank you @TalhaQ I will check out his blog.. but i do have Ant installed in the android directory (just to simplify things since idk whats it for)

Comment: @MBillau That works!! thanks wow.. that was really a silly mistake on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANDROID_HOME should point to `\sdk`, not `\sdk\platform-tools\`. This is because the build system uses things in both platform-tools and tools folders. Change that and try again in a new terminal window please.